# pandas group by custom column

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a following df:

| score | var1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0.465 | jack, jones, phil |
| 0.712 | don, sam, bob |
| 0.112 | jones, alex, sam |

I want to round column 'score' in such a way, so I would have for example a mean score of jones in such a way

| name | 0.1 (score) | 0.5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jones | 1 | 1 |
| jack | 0 | 1 |
| alex | 0 | 0 |

second and third column, are the rounded score, so if we have max score of 1, then we will have 10 column, and as shown in table above, it shows how much jones appeared with the rounded score of 0.1 and etc

I have a code written to similiar question as this, but instead of a score I just have boolean target column with 0 and 1. however, I cant figure how to do it in this case
this is the code:

```
out=(df
 .assign(cr_social_vector=df['var_1'].str.split(',\s*'),
         dev_var=np.where(df['target'].eq(1), 'dev_var_1', 'dev_var_0'),
         value=1
        )
 .explode('cr_social_vector')
 .pivot_table(index=['var_1', 'var_2'], columns='target', values='value',
              aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
 .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
 .groupby(['var_1'], as_index=False)
 .agg({'target_1': 'sum', 'target_0': 'sum', 'var_2': 'last'})
)
```

Comment: This really feels like an assignment question that you have not actually tried to solve yet. Please show us what you've got so far and focus the question on a specific problem.

Comment: Can you clarify the desired output? Why does jones have a `1` in the second column and alex and jack a `0`?

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar I have edited it. Jones appears once when score is 0.112 and once when score is 0.465

Comment: @joanis I have edited the q and showed what I have tried already

Comment: @Krish Thank you, that's a better question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
out_ = (df.assign(score=df['score'].round(1),
                var1=df['var1'].str.split(', '))
       .explode('var1'))

out = pd.crosstab(out_['var1'], out_['score'])
```

```
print(out_)

   score   var1
0    0.5   jack
0    0.5  jones
0    0.5   phil
1    0.7    don
1    0.7    sam
1    0.7    bob
2    0.1  jones
2    0.1   alex
2    0.1    sam


print(out)

score  0.1  0.5  0.7
var1
alex     1    0    0
bob      0    0    1
don      0    0    1
jack     0    1    0
jones    1    1    0
phil     0    1    0
sam      1    0    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'score':[0.465,0.712, 0.112],'var1':[['jack', 'jones', 'phil'],['don', 'sam', 'bob'],['jones', 'alex', 'sam']]})
 
df = df.round(decimals=1).explode("var1").pivot_table(index="var1",columns="score", aggfunc="size", fill_value=0).reset_index()
df
```

Output:

[image]